# "Unqualified exec" from Numpy when trying to run Django app

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

while running command python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002

```
   /..../python3.6_rhel7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:319: RuntimeWarning: Model 'dataServices.hsfiledetails' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.
      new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7ff94e236578>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/..../python3.6_rhel7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/..../dataServices/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .bugPred import *
File "/..../python3.6_rhel7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
        from . import core
      File "/..../python3.6_rhel7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from . import multiarray
      File "/..../python3.6_rhel7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
        from . import overrides
      File "/..../python3.6_rhel7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 182
        exec(source_object, scope)
SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'decorator' it is a nested function
```

> SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'decorator'
>   it is a nested function

above one is syntax error for "Unqualified exec" from Numpy when trying to run Django app

Comment: can you share more code ? what is line 182 ?

Comment: Is the error in your code or Django's? What's the relation to NumPy? Also, please edit the question title so people can make a meaning out of it. Suggestion: Take the error message as base. Further, which Python version do you use? Could it be that there's a mismatch between what the code expects and what you have? Also, how do you call this code and what is the backtrace it prints?

Comment: its Django  error , I am using python 3.6.7,

Comment: Please include the full traceback; we have no way to know which part of your code calls `numpy` from inside a decorator.

Comment: How does your app attempt to use Numpy anyway? We need more context to be able to tell you anything useful.

Comment: @tripleee , i added More context for same issue

Answer (score 2):

The mix of Python 2 and Python 3 libraries in the traceback suggests a probably irreconcileable configuration problem.

If your app needs to work with Python 3, you need to install Python 3 versions of all dependencies, and make very sure no Python 2 library paths leak over.

For Python 2, vice versa (but also think hard and fast about switching to Python 3 very soon).

I'm looking at

```
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
```

which clearly shows that you have something pulling in a Python 2 library, where all the other libraries in the traceback mention Python 3.6.  Python 2 and Python 3 are different languages and cannot easily be mixed (though with e.g. `six` you actually can).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same exception when running a Dash/Flask app. Exception occurs in numpy/core/overrides.py, line 188 of numpy 1.18.2. The exception appears by merely doing **import numpy** in the app. Indeed a mix of 2.7 and 3.6 caused my problem. I am forced to use CGI and I made the mistake of starting CGI with system default Python 2.7.5, but my app needed 3.6. This is probably the issue for the OP.
Here is an excerpt from my correct CGI:

```
#!/home/main_account/venv36/weather/bin/python
# Python virtualenv must be activated
activate_this = '/home/main_account/venv36/weather/bin/activate_this.py'

with open(activate_this) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), activate_this, 'exec')
    exec(code, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

The key is the very first line, the CGI must be run with the correct Python, activating the virtualenv is not sufficient.

I found a brief tutorial that shows you how to test that you've done it correctly: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/activating-a-python-virtual-environment-from-a-script-file